# Passing arrays as function parameter using rest parameter syntax

Tags: javascript

The following function takes in multiple values as parameter for its function using the rest parameter syntax.

Both `console.logs` will give the correct result `[1,2,3]`.

But shouldn't the first `console.log` give following result -> `[[1],[2],[3]]`  since it is not collecting 3 numbers but 3 arrays?

```js
function joinArrays(...vals) {
  return vals.reduce((acc, next) => acc.concat(next), []);
}

console.log(joinArrays([1], [2], [3]));
console.log(joinArrays(1, 2, 3));
```

Answer (score 4):

`concat` is a bit odd. It can either accept an array as an argument, in which case it will create a new array including all elements of both arrays:

```js
console.log(
  [1, 2].concat([3, 4])
);
```

Or, it can accept a *single element* as an argument, in which case it will create a new array including that one additional element:

```js
console.log(
  [1, 2].concat(3)
);
```

Here, your `joinArrays([1],[2],[3])` is doing the first process, taking every item from every array and creating a new array from those items.

Comment: +1, So in order to concat another array, we need to wrap it in a new array? for i.e.  `[1, 2].concat([[3], [4]])`

Comment: Yep, but that looks weird. I'd prefer `push` or spread, it'll be more readable.

Comment: @SamsonKemba Consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking the green tick on the left of the answer. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)